# Binary Search Tree error when deleting a leaf node

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I was testing my function to delete a node from a binary search tree but found out that I cannot delete a leaf node. Visual Studio gives me this error in the in_order function when it comes to printing the whole tree. - Exception thrown: read access violation.
tree was 0xDDDDDDDD.

Was wondering how to fix it because it works in all other cases so far.

```
void in_order(BinTreeNode* tree) {
    if (tree->left != NULL)
        in_order(tree->left);
    std::cout << tree->value << std::endl;
    if (tree->right != NULL)
        in_order(tree->right);
}


void deleteNodeFromBST(BinTreeNode* root_value, int key_value)
{
    BinTreeNode* selected_node = root_value;
    BinTreeNode* previous_selected_node = NULL;
    bool foundNode = false;

    /* find the node we want to delete */

    while (foundNode == false)
    {
        if (selected_node == NULL)
        {
            return; 
        }

        else
        {
            if (selected_node->value == key_value)
            {
                foundNode = true; 
            }

            else
            {
                previous_selected_node = selected_node;
                if (key_value > selected_node->value)
                    selected_node = selected_node->right;
                else
                    selected_node = selected_node->left; 
            }
        }
    }

    if (foundNode == false)
    {
        return;
    }


    /* if the node has no children, just delete it */

    if (selected_node->left == NULL && selected_node->right == NULL)
    {
        if (previous_selected_node->left == selected_node)
            previous_selected_node->left == NULL;
        else
            previous_selected_node->right = NULL;
        delete selected_node;
        return;
    }

    /* if the node has one child to the left , we replace the node with the child*/

    else if (selected_node->left != NULL && selected_node->right == NULL)
    {
        if (previous_selected_node->left == selected_node)
        {
            previous_selected_node->left = selected_node->left;
            delete selected_node;
            selected_node = NULL;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            previous_selected_node->right = selected_node->left;
            delete selected_node;
            selected_node = NULL;
            return;
        }
    }

    /* if the node has one child to the right, we replace the node with the child*/

    else if (selected_node->right != NULL && selected_node->left == NULL)
    {
        if (previous_selected_node->right == selected_node)
        {
            previous_selected_node->right = selected_node->right;
            delete selected_node;
            selected_node = NULL;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            previous_selected_node->left = selected_node->right;
            delete selected_node;
            selected_node = NULL;
            return; 
        }
    }

    /*if the node we want to delete has two children, we find the max value in the left subtree and we replace it */

    else if (selected_node->left != NULL && selected_node->right != NULL)
    {
        BinTreeNode* maxLeftValue = selected_node->left;
        BinTreeNode* maxLeftValuePrev = selected_node; 


        while (maxLeftValue->right != NULL)
        {
            maxLeftValuePrev = maxLeftValue;
            maxLeftValue = maxLeftValue->right;
        }

        selected_node->value = maxLeftValue->value;

        if (maxLeftValue->left != NULL)
        {
            maxLeftValuePrev->right = maxLeftValue->left;
        }
        else
        {
            maxLeftValuePrev = NULL;
        }
        delete maxLeftValue;
        maxLeftValue = NULL;
        return; 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //BinTreeNode* t = tree_insert(0, 6);
    /*tree_insert(t, 10);
    tree_insert(t, 5);
    tree_insert(t, 2);
    tree_insert(t, 3);
    tree_insert(t, 4);
    tree_insert(t, 11);*/
    BinTreeNode* t = tree_insert(0, 20);
    tree_insert(t, 15);
    tree_insert(t, 19);
    tree_insert(t, 11);
    tree_insert(t, 13);
    tree_insert(t, 9);
    tree_insert(t, 12);
    tree_insert(t, 5);
    tree_insert(t, 2);
    tree_insert(t, 3);


    deleteNodeFromBST(t, 16);
    deleteNodeFromBST(t, 19);
    deleteNodeFromBST(t, 13);
    deleteNodeFromBST(t, 11);



    in_order(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Visual Studio* -- This includes one of the best debuggers in the industry.  Why not use it to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

change the last few lines in function:

```
void deleteNodeFromBST(BinTreeNode* root_value, int key_value)
{
    .
    .
    .
    else if (selected_node->left != NULL && selected_node->right != NULL)
    {
         .
         .
         .

        if(maxLeftValuePrev->left == maxLeftValue)
            maxLeftValuePrev->left = maxLeftValue->left;
        else
            maxLeftValuePrev->right = maxLeftValue->left;
        delete maxLeftValue;
        maxLeftValue = NULL;
        return;
    }
}
```

The logic in your code is:
if the node we want to delete has two children, we find the max value in the left subtree(The rightmost node of the subtree) and we replace it, and delete this rightmost node of the subtree--"`maxLeftValue`". You should set `maxLeftValuePrev-right` to NULL but not `maxLeftValuePrev`

Comment: I don't think you tested this.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
if (maxLeftValue->left != NULL)
    {
        maxLeftValuePrev->right = maxLeftValue->left;
    }
    else
    {
        maxLeftValuePrev = NULL;
    }
```

contains two errors. First, as @DrakeWu pointed out, the second assignment is incorrect; it assigns a new value to a local variable, which is never used again, and the tree can be left with a pointer to a node that has been deleted. Second, the first assignment *assumes that `maxLeftValue` is a right-child.* If (as can happen) it is a left-child, then one node can become the child of two different nodes, so that *the tree ceases to be a tree.*

Here is one way to correct this code:

```
if(maxLeftValuePrev->left == maxLeftValue)
    maxLeftValuePrev->left = maxLeftValue->left;
else
    maxLeftValuePrev->right = maxLeftValue->left;
```

(Also, your naming conventions are bad-- you should not give a *node* a name that ends with *"Value"*.)